# Visual Studio 2013 - Rename Build Output

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I renamed my project and everything in Visual Studio, but when I build the solution, everything is named as ConsoleApplication1. I would like to know how to change this. Thanks!

I also found it surprising that I couldn't find any answers to this rather simple question. I thought it would be a common one. Even Google turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the Project > Properties > Application > Assembly name